# Woocommerce Add to Cart Condition

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I recently implement the code in function.php to redirect url when the price is 0 but it seems its only lacking and the price condition is not working. See my codes.

```
/**
 * Set a custom add to cart URL to redirect to
 * @return string
 **/

function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
      $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
      if( $product->get_price() == 0 ||  $product->get_price() == '') {
        return 'http://www.nichegas.ads-tracker.com/contact/'; 
        }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

It seems I am lacking on some code or something. 
Our objective are:
 1. IF price is 0 it will redirect to out custom url
 2  also when click the add to card and its zero its will not add the item to the cart. How to disable the addition of product?

Your help will very much appreciated. Have a nice day!

Comment: your code is right simply replace $product->get_price() to $_product->get_price()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> Alternatively you can use also **`woocommerce_add_to_cart`** hook instead, and **here is possible to remove the freshly added item, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id ) {

    $_product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $_product_price = $_product->get_price();
    if( $_product_price == 0 || empty($_product_price) ) {

        // Removing this freshly added cart item
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);

        // Redirecting to some url
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.nichegas.ads-tracker.com/contact/' );

        exit; 
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.

Comment: I think this will help greatly. I will check it. I will let you know

Comment: it work perfectly... thanks a lot... btw, on redirect. it is possible to pass the information like product name to a form?